# How can i find out the Last row in a datagridview and write it to text file

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to find the last row of the datagridview and i would like to write that particular row data to a text file can any one help me

Comment: In which way do you want the values to be written to a textfile? with/without column names, comma separated, XmlSerialized, ... ?

Comment: Just i would like to write the data as a plain with out column names and other

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will give you a sample code, it may help.

```
 List<string> lstContents = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in mydataGrid.Rows[mydataGrid.RowCount - 1].Cells)
        {
            lstContents .Add((string)cell.Value);
        }
 string myData= string.Join(",", lstContents.ToArray());
```

Now using streamwriter you can write this string to your file. Also you can use any separator. I have used "," comma here.
///This will append data to your text file...

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FilePath, true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(myData);
        }
```

Comment: Hi small help if i need to write only particular cell data then what should i do

Comment: You mean particular cell data in the last row?

Comment: If you want particular cell data, you can modify the above code like this: reomve the foreach loop, and in sw.WriteLine(mydataGrid.Rows[mydataGrid.RowCount - 1].Cells[yourCellNumber]);   put zero based cell number that you need data of